# NSAttributedString with Attributes in Swift 2.1

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

Recently, I have updated to `Xcode 7.0` and the following code which was working fine in `Swift 1.2` is giving me error in `Swift 2.0`

```
let messageString = inString
let attributes = [UIFont(): UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0)]
let attrString:NSAttributedString? = NSAttributedString(string: messageString, attributes: attributes)
```

Can anyone know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your attributes this way:

```
    let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0)]
```